# Is there a recording of Chopin's "Winter Wind" with the drums added, as heard in Your Lie In April?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

I've looked everywhere for that Etude in A minor Op. 25 No. 11 with drums, as that song sounded so epic in the anime!! Any idea if that version of the song is purchasable or located anywhere online?

Answer (score 2):

There is an album of the pieces actually from the show, called [Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso: Our Music Book](https://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.fandom.com/wiki/Shigatsu_wa_Kimi_no_Uso:_Our_Music_Book). Unfortunately, based on a version I found on YouTube, it seems like the Winter Wind on that album is just a standard rendition of the piece (presumably from the main recital). On that basis, I suspect that there isn't an officially released copy of the version with drums.